# DocuSign : Getting connection timedout while using the Java program in the Demo site.

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am new to DocuSign.

Started trying with the basic Login authentication in Java. Used the code snippet in the below link.

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeRecipientStatus#java

Getting the below exception.

**Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: conn
ect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewH
ttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown So
urce)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unk
nown Source)
        at GetEnvelopeInfo.main(GetEnvelopeInfo.java:56)**

Tried to Ping the server address. got the same Request timed out error.

ping demo.docusign.net

Pinging demo.docusign.net.akadns.net [209.46.117.172] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the proxy information for your environment.  The jvm parameters are http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort.  It can be set by using 
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "yourProxyHostname");

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.  Tried with adding the below lines. System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","myProxy");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","8080"); But the result is same. Connection timed out.

Comment: You will need the correct host and port for the proxy